# Change align of a single cell in tabular while using multicolumn

Tags: tables

I would like the texts in the final row, to be left aligned completely. (Visual Preference Score.)

```
\begin{tabular}{| *{6}{c|} }
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Visual}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Auditory}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Tactile}}                \\ \hline
        
        No. & Points. & No. & Points. & No. & Points. \\ \hline
        2 & & 1 & & 4& \\ \hline
            3 & & 5 & & 6& \\ \hline
                7 & & 8 & & 9& \\ \hline
                    10 & & 11 & & 12& \\ \hline
                        14 & & 13 & & 15& \\ \hline
                            16 & & 18 & & 17& \\ \hline
                                19 & & 21 & & 20& \\ \hline
                                    22 & & 24 & & 23& \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Visual Preference Score : } & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Auditory Preference Score : } & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Tactile Preference Score : } \\
        \hline
        
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image: This is the output.]

This is the output that I am getting.

Comment: Can you add a compilable test document? From your image, I'd say they are left aligned, but you increased the spacing around columns somewhere in your document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please extend your code snippet to something compilable so that it becomes a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). With only this little code, it is impossible to provide a reasonable answer as the code you provided compiles fine with the text in the cells in the last row aligned to the left properly if pasted in a minimal document file.

Comment: Is `\multicolumn{2}{|@{}l|}{Visual Preference Score : } & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{Auditory Preference Score : } & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{Tactile Preference Score : }` what you are looking for?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes. I didn't know about @{}.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I'm assuming you want the three "Points" columns to have equal widths.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt} % for a less-cramped look
\begin{tabular}{| *{3}{ c| w{c}{3.5cm}| } } % 3 groups of column pairs
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Visual}}   & 
   \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Auditory}} & 
   \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Tactile}}  \\ \hline
   No. & Points. & No. & Points. & No. & Points. \\ \hline
    2 & &  1 & &  4 & \\ \hline
    3 & &  5 & &  6 & \\ \hline
    7 & &  8 & &  9 & \\ \hline
   10 & & 11 & & 12 & \\ \hline
   14 & & 13 & & 15 & \\ \hline
   16 & & 18 & & 17 & \\ \hline
   19 & & 21 & & 20 & \\ \hline
   22 & & 24 & & 23 & \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|@{}l|}{\,Visual Preference Score : } & 
   \multicolumn{2}{ @{}l|}{\,Auditory Preference Score : } & 
   \multicolumn{2}{ @{}l|}{\,Tactile Preference Score : } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was what I was looking for.